# Visual Studio 2022: Solution-level folders not showing in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution hosted in Azure DevOps.  On DevOps, the folder structure looks like this (note the Deployment and Infrastructure folders):

[image]

But in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, these folders don't show (either inside or outside of the Solution Items folder:

[image]

What **does** show are the files contained in the Deployment and Infrastructure folders (pipeline.yml and infrastructure.yml, respectively).  But not their containing folders.

I have verified that the folder structure in the file system via Windows Explorer correctly matches what's on the remote repo:

[image]

But why aren't these subfolders appearing in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer?  Is this merely an idiosyncrasy with how Visual Studio is designed to work that I just need to live with?

Comment: BTW, Git repository directories aren't the same thing as Visual Studio _Solution Folders_ - and the folders/directories in Projects (not Solutions) are scoped to the project-root, which isn't usually the solution-root, nor the repo root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch solution view and folder view using the following button.

[image]

Comment: Not ideal, but good enough :-).  It would be nicer, in my opinion, if VS offered an option giving the "best of both worlds" between folder view and solution view

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have this option marked when selecting your solution:

[image: Show all files button at the top bar of visual studio 2022 solution explorer]

Then just select the folders and include them in the solution.